# How do I pass an aliased array reference in a MooseX::Method::Signatures method?

Tags: perl, moose, method-signature

[MooseX::Method::Signatures](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aSignatures) should be able to obtain an array reference as a parameter and use it as a normal array within the method, see [*Aliased references* in Method::Signatures](http://p3rl.org/Method%3a%3aSignatures#Aliased-references).

Using the code in the documentation as an example, I've written:

```
package MethodSignatures;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Method::Signatures;

method add_one(\@foo) {
    $_++ for @foo;
}

my @bar = ( 1, 2, 3 );
MethodSignatures->add_one(\@bar);    # @bar is now (2,3,4)
```

However, it fails with:

```
')' expected whilst parsing signature near '@foo' in '\@foo' at d:/workspace/lib/tools/Perl/site/lib/MooseX/Method/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm line 199
```

Is this because I am using Perl 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that [MooseX::Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aSignatures) is something different from [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/Method%3a%3aSignatures). The former does not mention `\@foo` syntax as allowed for prototype, so it may be reason for fail.

Both modules are for perl 5, so this should not be reason for the error.